# Encryption software for Windows with no memory limit

Tags: windows, encryption

I used Knox on the Mac which is a file/folder encryption software. However, I am moving over to Windows, so I'm looking for a similar software that does the same thing.

I basically need a software that will encrypt my files and folders, using 256-bit Advanced Encryption Standard (or better). I will need to use a password to unlock it. I also like to send encrypted vaults to people who can then unlock it with the password.

The typical encryption software I have seen on Windows including Kaspersky is that when you create a new data encryption you have to specify the size of the vault.

For example, I created a data encryption vault of 1GB. But I work with very large files and I maxed this out very quickly. There is no way to increase the memory size of the vault once you created it. It is set in stone.

Things I need
- Ideally, work with Mac and Windows. 
- Can share the vault and they can use the password to unlock it
- 256-bit Advanced Encryption Standard or better
- Easy to use
- Must not have set memory size

I'm happy to use a free or paid for software

Answer (score 1):

You can use Trucrypt or Veracrypt.

When creating a volume you choose that it should be "dynamically sized".

It still requires a maximum size to be set but it won't be allocated so it can be very big. The actual size on disk will depend on the files inside the volume so you can still share it easily. It will only increase over time though, deleting files will not decrease the on-disk size.

Comment: Just tried this when I tried to add larger files it says not enough space. Doesn't seem to work

Comment: 7-zip can encrypt files using AES-256 when archiving them. Additional files can be added as needed, either using one password for all or separate passwords. An advantage of this method is that most OS's can unencrypt a Zip file (though not all handle other formats). However, 7-zip has native Windows and Linux binaries, if needed (not sure about Mac).

Answer (score 0):

[ccrypt](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/) can encrypt a file of any size with a password, using 256-bit Rijndael. To encrypt several files into one "vault", just combine them into a ZIP file first.